# Repeating a combination of commands mapped to a single key

Tags: repeated-commands

I have a mapping to "**S**tamp" text over the current word that cursor is on: `nnoremap S "_diwP`. When I do `S` and then try to repeat it with dot `.` only the last command will be repeated: `P`.

Is it possible in vim to alter the mapping (somehow grouping the commands?) so that `.` will repeat all of it? In other words, is it possible to repeat a compound command like `"_diwP` with `.` in vim?

Close to being answers:

- I know that in this particular case the command could be rewritten with `c` instead of `d`+`p`.
- Also the command could be recorded as a macro and repeated with `@` but that is not as convenient as using `.`

Answer (score 2):

If you have tpope's [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat), you can do something like the following:

```
nnoremap S :call Stamp()<CR>

function Stamp() abort
  normal! "_diwP
  silent! call repeat#set("S", -1)
endfunction
```

You can do it without the function, but this is a bit clearer in my opinion.

Comment: I recommend adding a `<silent>` to the `nnoremap` so the `:call` doesn't flash the command-line...

Comment: You know, it's funny, I actually [removed `<silent>`](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/commit/661cb1bc1069e312df552e3035e776a3b4109842) from most of my personal mappings recently; I found that I didn't really care about seeing the "flash," and it occasionally reminded me what was really going on. That said, your map, your modifiers :) @filbranden